# sent apk file from bluestacks to android mobile phone

Tags: android

I am using bluestacks**strong text** and i want to sent the **strong text**.apk game file to my another android mobile phone. can any body help me**strong text**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install a software(AndroZip)  to create apk file of that game in bluestack. Then you can transfer the apk from shared folder to your mobile or anywhere you want .

How to get location of storage of bluestack ? 
Try this links :

[Link 1](http://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/203081537-How-to-Access-Files-on-your-PC-from-BlueStacks-)
[Link 2](http://7labs.heypub.com/tips-tricks/how-to-access-your-computers-files-in-bluestacks-on-windows.html)